# Fluid and fixed column

Tags: html, css

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/TPKLv/

```
<div style="background-color:white; width: 400px;">
<span class="status" id="active"></span><a href="detail.html" class="title">Title</a>
<a href="#" class="number">6</a>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: white; float:right;">
Test test
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the right column fluid, taking up the remaining space, and the left column fixed width. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with my code, and if this is the best way of doing it?

Comment: what is your browser support requirement?? you need support for IE8 or below too?

Comment: IE8+ but earlier is better

Comment: you can't have it unless you use JS! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to use `display:table-cell;` (*IE8 and above supported* )

this way, you can fix the width of one div and next div will take up the remaining space

Once added, you can even use `inline` native methods like `vertical-align`, and since its not `float`ing, adjusting the position of divs is easy through `margin` and `padding` depending on you layout! :)

[check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/7/)

It is most compatible and cleanest you can get for fixed width and dynamic width in a page

for `calc`, [it is incompatible with IE9 still](http://caniuse.com/calc)

---

if you have to use it on regular basis, create a `span` as below :

```
span.fake_width{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
}
```

then just add it to the existing layout  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/8/)

Comment: This is a good option, thank you. Is it possible to have a 20 px gap between the two columns though with this technique?

Comment: @Jimmy : added answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this, with the condition always left `div` width is `400px`. And i assume is cause you use `inline-style`

**html**

```
<div style="background-color:white; width: 400px;float:left;">
<span class="status" id="active"></span><a href="detail.html" class="title">Title</a>
<a href="#" class="number">6</a>
</div>
<div id="rightCol" style="background-color: white; float:right;">
Test test
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {background-color: gray;}

#rightCol{
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without ```calc``` since it isn't that compatible with older browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The most native way of doing this is to manipulate the box model:
I've added a float to the first div, and removed it from the second one.
this way the first div is treated as an inline-block and the second one is a block, which tries hard to ignore other inline blocks.

i've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/3/

```
<div style="background-color:white; width: 400px; float:left">
    <span class="status" id="active"></span><a href="detail.html" class="title">Title</a>
    <a href="#" class="number">6</a>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: white;">
   Test test
</div>
```

Comment: If I may, how would I get a 20px gap between the two columns, this is what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/TPKLv/5/

Comment: Actually stick a `margin-right: 20px;` on the floated element.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    background-color:blue;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
    width: 100px;
}
.content {
    background-color:green;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">        
    <div class="sidebar">
      <span class="status " id="active"></span>
        <a href="detail.html" class="title">Title</a>    
         <a href="#" class="number">6</a>    
    </div>

    <div class="content">Test test</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATED FIDDLE** **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/TPKLv/10/)**.

As you need, I added padding and margin for the div's and its working fine.

Comment: Is there a way to have a 20px gap between the two columns as padding or margin on either column doesnt seem to work

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` will be a havoc when browser would be resized...!! :)

Comment: @Jimmy, Updated my answer with fiddle demo as per your need.